# SharePoint 2019/Subscription Edition -- SQL Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql

I have been working with SharePoint for the better part of 15 years. During that time, I almost always installed SharePoint in a domain environment where the Application Server(s) and Database Server(s) were within the same AD domain.

I am increasingly seeing use cases where SharePoint could/should be in a DMZ and simply having SharePoint utilise a SQL server cluster (deployed in a different domain, for example). Therefore, I would like to explore using SQL-based authentication between the SharePoint Application Server(s) and the backend database server(s).

Historically Microsoft's support for that was always grey at best. The "support" was typically limited to a subset of services (e.g. a Content DB). And the wider SharePoint farm (and services) still needed to be deployed within the same domain at the SQL server.

Can you point me to some documentation/article that outlines how to install SharePoint 2019 (or Subscription Edition) where all of SharePoint is authenticating to its SQL backend using SQL Authentication (rather than Windows authentication)?

Comment: The documentation suggests that you must use a domain account for SharePoint server service accounts. If you want to confirm this beyond all doubt, you could raise a question with the documentation (via GitHub) or via Microsoft support. https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/install/initial-deployment-administrative-and-service-accounts-in-sharepoint-server#required-accounts-in-sharepoint-server

Comment: Thanks, @CallumCrowley. I'd expect to create Service Accounts within an AD domain in the DMZ. Do you have experience with the SQL server being in a different domain, untrusted and unconnected to the domain the SharePoint Application server(s) are in? Meaning the SharePoint servers would authenticate to SQL using SQL Authentication rather than Windows Authentication via the SharePoint Service accounts.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be supported, as alluded to in the documentation (it specifically notes that the SQL server service account needs to be a Windows domain account). I therefore have no experience of this, as I have only configured farms according to what Microsoft recommend. If you really want to push the idea, you could raise a question with the documentation (via GitHub) or via Microsoft support.

Comment: There is some conflicting information here because the following documentation discusses creating a SharePoint Content DB in Azure SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sambetts/hosting-sharepoint-content-databases-in-sql-azure

Comment: Second paragraph in: "this is currently not officially supported for SharePoint Server, even for Azure-hosted farms."